# link_to problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to display product count in a link_to, the link_to is a part of partial displayed in application.erb.html, the problem is, I have a method in my application controller named products_on_cart which return products count, when I try this code:

```
<%= link_to "<%= products_on_cart%>", :controller=>"carts", :action=>"index"%>
```

rails give me an error:

> "syntax error, unexpected '>'
>   ...er=>"carts", :action=>"index"%>"

I don't really understand why, can somebody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `<%= .. %>` inside of `<%= .. %>`.

```
<%= link_to products_on_cart, [:carts] %>
```

Comment: another problem appears, now rails cannot see my products_on_cart method which is in application controller

Comment: in ApplicationController:

    helper_method :products_on_cart

Answer (score 3):

You're nesting ERb tags.  Make sure `products_on_cart()` is available as a helper method, then rewrite your `link_to` code without nested ERb tags as follows:

```
<%= link_to products_on_cart(), :controller => "carts", :action => "index" %>
```

To make `products_on_cart()` a helper method, either move it to `app/helpers/application.rb`, or declare it as a helper in your controller:

```
def products_on_cart()
  # method definition goes here
end

helper_method :products_on_cart
```

If you only need to access `products_on_cart` from your views and not from your controllers, putting it in `app/helpers/application.rb` is the preferred way to go.  If you need to use it in both controllers and views, use the `helper_method` approach above instead.